# How do I deploy and upload a React App to Hostinger?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently finished building a React Portfolio Website that used smooth scrolling and Im having trouble deploying it.  I ran npm run build and uploaded it to Hostiger, however im confused as to if I also have to upload all of files and folders associated with my website as well.  As of right now I have uploaded the build to my public.html folder but it does not load.  Any tips and info please?

Comment: You’ll need to upload everything inside your build folder and not the build folder to your public folder in hostinger

Answer (score 0):

> [This url to helpful to deploy react app to hostinger](https://medium.com/@kmchaplain/deploying-a-react-application-on-hostinger-cf2c6c43b072)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `file name.env` same level of `package.json` with the following code inside:

```
PUBLIC_URL=https://hostinger-react-app.com
```

then run the command

```
npm run build
```

and you should get the following message:

"The project was built assuming it is hosted at https://hostinger-react-app.com./."